# Updating the Posterior Psi parameter for an Inverse Wishart Distribution

Tags: bayesian, covariance-matrix, matrix, garch, matrix-inverse

I am fitting a Mixed Multivariate Normal Distribution where the mixing occurs over the mean $\mu_j$ and the covariance matrix $H$ with mixing parameter $B_j$. The number of mixing elements is denotes by $j$ (and $n_j$ the number of observations assigned to a particular cluster mix). In order to optimize for $\mu_j$ and $B_j$ I perform an MCMC, where the posterior distribution for parameter $B$ equals:

$B_{j} \mid r_{1: T}, s_{1: T}, \mu_{j}, \Gamma \sim \mathcal{W}^{-1}\left(n_{j}+\nu_{0}, B_{0}+\sum_{s_{t}=j}\left(H_{t}^{-1 / 2}\mathbf{x_{t}}-H_{t}^{-1 / 2} \mathbf{\mu}_{j}\right)\left(H_{t}^{-1 / 2}\mathbf{x_{t}}-H_{t}^{-1 / 2} \mathbf{\mu}_{j}\right)^{\prime}\right)$

However I run into a problem of the updating of the $\Psi$ parameter of the inverse Wishart distribution.
$\Psi = \sum_{s_{t}=j}\left(H_{t}^{-1 / 2}\mathbf{x_{t}}-H_{t}^{-1 / 2} \mu_{j}\right)\left(H_{t}^{-1 / 2}\mathbf{x_{t}}-H_{t}^{-1 / 2} \mu_{j}\right)^{\prime}$

The problem is that the update is not positive definite.
The data that I am working with are financial returns which sometimes are negative, hence for some cross multiplications, the result will be negative.
In addition, taking the inverse of the cholesky decomposition $(H_t^{-1/2})$ of $H$ does not return a symmetric matrix, thus also fails to keep $\Psi$ positive definite.

Does someone perhaps have an idea what could alleviate this problem?

Comment: @Xi'an Yes thank you, I adjusted it.